# Is it possible to deactivate MongoHealthIndicator in the Springboot spring actuator health endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In the springboot project that I work on there is a transitive maven dependency on spring-data-mongodb. Therefore the MongoHealthIndicator seems to be activated automatically although the project does not actually use mongodb. Is it possible to deactivate specifically this HealthIndicator without deactivating the actuator health endpoint? A workaround that I found is excluding the dependency. But I was wondering if it is possible to do this specific deactivation of the MongoHealthIndicator.

Comment: You can disable it, BUT the health indicator will only start if a `MongoTemplate` is available as a bean, which in turn will only be available if there is a mongo instance active. So you probably are starting more then yu think (which probably influences (startup) performance of your application).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

```
# HEALTH INDICATORS (previously health.*)
...
management.health.mongo.enabled=true
...
```

You should be able to set that to false to disable the health indicator. From org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(MongoTemplate.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "management.health.mongo", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public static class MongoHealthIndicatorConfiguration {
```

Comment: This was indeed very helpful. Thanks for concise ans and link. I think ideally, property should have been used in very opposite way in spring boot. Enable only what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Try this in your application.properties

```
management.health.mongo.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 2):

**application.properties**

> management.health.mongo.enabled=false
>   endpoints.mongo.enabled=true

**MongoDBHealthCheckEndPoint.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "endpoints.mongo", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
@Component
public class MongoDBHealthCheckEndPoint extends AbstractEndpoint<Map<String, String>> 
{

    @Inject
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    private static final Map<String, String> UP = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("mongo.status", "UP");
    }};

    private static final Map<String, String> DOWN = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("mongo.status", "DOWN");
    }};


    public MongoDBHealthCheckEndPoint() {
        super("mongo", false);
    }

    public MongoDBHealthCheckEndPoint(Map<String, ? extends Object> mongo) {
        super("mongo", false);
    }

    public Map<String, String> invoke() {
        try {
            return (new MongoHealthIndicator(mongoTemplate).health().getStatus().equals(Status.UP)) ? UP : DOWN;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("mongo database is down", e);
            return DOWN;
        }
    }
}
```